# Compute the Jacobian matrix of a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R}^6$ such that for any $p=(p_1, p_2, p_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $q=(q_1, q_2, q_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ it is
$$f(p,q) = \left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{1+|p|^2}}, \frac{q}{|q|^3}\right).$$

My question is: how to compute the determinant of the Jacobian of that function? Clearly, I know the definition of Jacobian matrix, but I don't how to compute it in that case. During the class, the Professor said that we need to compute
$$\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial p_j}(p, q) =\delta_{ij}(1+|p|^2)^{-1/2}-p_i p_j(1+|p|^2)^{-3/2},$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f^{1+i}}{\partial q_j}(p, q) =\delta_{ij}|q|^{-3} -3q_i q_j |q|^{-5},$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta and $i, j =1, 2, 3$.
Possibly I am a bit confused about the fact that I have a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^6$, but I don't understand why we need to compute all that things. Could someone please explain it to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want the Jacobian matrix, you have to compute $\frac{\partial f^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\{1,\dots, 6\}$. Here, you have a split into $6=3+3$ variables into $x=(p,q)$, hence you're computing those derivatives. (Also, you said $f$ is defined on $\Bbb{R}^6$, but it's not. You only defined it on a certain open subset of $\Bbb{R}^6$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo but why the notation $\partial f^{i+1}$? It has to be $i\ne j$? Moreover, I don't see what $f^1,\dots f^6$ are. Could you please help?

Comment: You do see that your function has target space $\Bbb{R}^6$ right? Just look at the definition you gave. Also I'm pretty sure it should be $f^{3+i}$. Also, because of the way the function is defined, the Jacobian matrix has a certain block structure which is what they're trying to emphasize by getting youbto calculate those particular partial derivatives.

Comment: +1 already for properly writing down definition and value space ...

Answer (score 3):

Denote the new variable
$$
\mathbf{u} = 
\frac{\mathbf{p}}{\sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}}
$$
it follows
$$
u_1
=
\frac{p_1}{\sqrt{1+p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2}}
$$
you are asked to compute
$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial p_1}$,
$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial p_2}$,
$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial p_3}$,
$\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial q_1}=0$,
etc
and identically for all the variables.

You can also work directly with vectors using differentials
$$
d\mathbf{u} \sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}+
\frac12 \frac{\mathbf{u}}{\sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}} (d\| \mathbf{p} \|^2)
=
d\mathbf{p}
$$
Now using $d\| \mathbf{p} \|^2 = 2 \mathbf{p}^T d\mathbf{p}$, you find that
$$
d\mathbf{u} 
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}}d\mathbf{p}
-
\frac{\mathbf{u}}{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2} \mathbf{p}^T d\mathbf{p}
$$
The Jacobian (at least one subblock) is
$$
\mathbf{J}_{up}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}} 
\left[
\mathbf{I}
-
\frac{\mathbf{u}\mathbf{p}^T}{\sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}}
\right]=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}} 
\color{#0048BA}{
\left[
\mathbf{I}
-
\frac{\mathbf{p}\mathbf{p}^T}{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}
\right]
}
$$
**UPDATE**

The matrix determinant lemma can be used to compute the determinant of this block
$$
\det(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T)=
(1+\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u}) \det(\mathbf{A})
$$
which simplifies here in
$$
\det(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T)=
1+\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{u}
\tag{1}
$$

Comment: Steph, thank you fir the answer. There is a "fast" way to compute the determinant of the Jacobian?

Comment: are you sure you need the determinant of the Jacobian ? I will use properties of block-partitioned matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) you will end up to compute 3-by-3 determinants again with a particular structure...

Comment: Using the notations of wikipedia, in our case it would be det(A)det(D), but A and D are 3x3 matrices. There is some trick I can use?

Comment: Note the particular structure of the 3-by-3 matrix. Do you see anything special ?

Comment: Ehm..actually no

Comment: It is the determinant of a matrix with a rank-one update. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: Actually I don't understand what you mean. Could you please integrate your answer with some more details about that. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Steph sorry, I continue not to understand why this writing of the matrix is true. And how to evaluate the determinant in this case, what computations I need to do. Sorry.

Comment: @C.Bishop. Simply use $\mathbf{u}=\frac{\mathbf{p}}{\sqrt{1+\| \mathbf{p} \|^2}}$ and  $\mathbf{v}=-\mathbf{u}$ in the formula (1).